approximate value of Dedekind eta function
approximate value of $\eta(\frac{i}{\sqrt{24N}})$ , Where $N$ is a large positive integer ?

Posted just yesterday, closed, and soon to be deleted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/476581/convergence-of-an-infinite-product-series

$$\eta\left(i\,x \right)\simeq \frac{\exp(-\frac{\pi}{12x})}{\sqrt{x}}\quad\quad x\to 0^+$$
$$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{24N}}\quad\quad N\to+\infty$$
https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/DedekindEta/06/02/01/ with $z=i\,x$
